# Главная диагональ матрицы (StringGrid) в Delphi

Tags: delphi, алгоритм

Дано: двумерный массив целых чисел `A[N, N]`.
Найти: произведение элементов, расположенных на главной диагонали.

```
 procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
 var
 a : Array [1..100, 1..100] of integer;
 i , j , sum : integer;
 begin
 for I := 1 to 100 do
 begin
 for J := 1 to 100 do
  begin
     if (i = j) then
        begin
          sum := sum * a [i, j];
          Edit2.Text := intToStr (sum);
        end;

  end;

 end;

 end;
```

Как составить код для прохода по главной диагонали?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы делаете почти правильно.

Нужно:

- Переименовать переменную `sum` в `product`
- Инициализировать её единицей (!)
- Выводить результат лишь в самом конце вычисления
- Вам не нужен двойной цикл и проверка индексов, достаточно цикла по `i` и обращения к диагональному элементу `a[i, i]`.
- Да, и не забудьте внести в матрицу данные, а то произведение чего считает ваш код?

Дальше сами.